# How to check of an object has been created in Perl?

Tags: perl, object

In my script, I have something like

```
my $region = $self->Functiontofind( $tag );

my $value1 = $region->getValue1;
my $value2 = $region->getValue2;
```

$region is an object,in some cases $region may be empty, i.e, if the tag is empty, I want to do a check to see if the object is empty or not. How can we do this.

`if (defined ($region))` does not seem to work.

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly in terms of the implementation do you mean that `$region` may be empty? We'll be able to give you a helpful answer most quickly if you edit your question to include the definition of `Functiontofind`.

Comment: "does not work" is pretty vague. What do you get, and what are you expecting?

Answer (score 3):

You should check what values can be returned by `Functiontofind`, it could be that: 0 = error, 1 = success, etc.

as already mentioned, ideally, its `undef` for not created (as you put it).

Btw, not relevant to this post I guess, but this reminds me the usefuleness of `Moose`'s *Predicate and clearer methods* which are very useful to explicitly distinguish between a false or undefined attribute value and an attribute which has not been set.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $region;
```

This will tell you what `$region` really is.

I suspect this will work:

```
use Scalar::Util;
if( defined( $region ) && ref( $region ) && blessed( $region )){
```

See:

perldoc Data::Dumper

perldoc Scalar::Util and search for /blessed/

Comment: In a *boolean* context, `blessed( $region )` should be enough--because the boolean context does not complain about undefs.

Answer (score 1):

if `Functiontofind`returns something other than `undef` when nothing is found, then you'll have to find out *what* it returns in that case, and build your test around it. If it's still some kind of object, but a different kind, [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) might do, or possibly `isa` (from [UNIVERSAL](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html)).

But your module might just return an object of the same class, but with some attributes empty. You might have to test for that... In that case I'd suggest adding a method just to test if an object of this class is empty.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, I'd have `Functiontofind` return something *always* and then use a method of `$region` like `isEmpty` or something to decide whether it's empty or not rather than return nothing if no match was found. However, if you want, you can test whether `$region == undef` to see whether it is not defined.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: You can't test `$region == undef`,  the way to test if a variable is defined or not is : `defined $region`

Comment: My perl very rusty. Can you explain what the equality test with `undef` does? I seem to recollect using it to do something like this. Here's an example. - http://pastebin.com/cRXKW4g9

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: in this case, it will return always true because you make a numerical test `==` $region will be cast to 0 and undef too.

Comment: In my pastebin example, the first evaluates to true and the second to false.

Comment: If $region is a reference to an object, it's evaluated as true (unless it's undefined) in boolean context an as 0 in numerical context.

Comment: @Noufal when used where Perl is expecting a string, undef is treated as an empty string. When used where Perl is expecting a number, undef is treated as a zero. You have the later in $region == undef. Try your program with $foo = 0; and see it give the wrong output...